# Error in json-c library

Tags: c, json

I am trying to parse a string of more than 500 bytes using  json_object * jobj = json_tokener_parse(my->src); where my->src contains the string, but I am getting the below error in one of the json-c library files while using gdb to debug:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
json_object_get_object (jso=0xfffffffc) at json_object.c:255
255     json_object.c: No such file or directory.
       in json_object.c
```

Can anyone let me know, what might be wrong.

Comment: What does json_object.c, line 255 do?

Comment: What exactly are the contents of `my->src`?

Comment: struct lh_table* json_object_get_object(struct json_object *jso)
{
  if(!jso) return NULL;
  switch(jso->o_type) {
  case json_type_object:
    return jso->o.c_object;
  default:
    return NULL;
  }
}

Comment: above piece of code is there around line 255.

Comment: @ChrisLutz: it is a pointer to the data I am retrieving from a Berkeley DB file.

Answer (score 2):

you want to test for:

```
if (is_error(jso)) {
  // handle error here
}
```

before doing anything else. for whatever reason the library returns a bogus pointer instead of null, and doesn't really document this (is_error is defined in json/bits.h).

Comment: Update from the future: is_error has been deprecated, and the library will return a null pointer

Library issue reference: https://github.com/json-c/json-c/issues/304

Answer (score 1):

A segmentation fault indicates mismanaged memory, for example a double `free`, or in your case  an unterminated string, a buffer overrun, or just a memory management error in json-c. Notably, the memory corruption can occur way before the segmentation fault, and might just (pseudo-)randomly show up when you decode the JSON input.

I strongly advise to run the program under a debugger such as [gdb](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/), and/or a memory access checker such as [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/), which will find memory management errors before the segmentaion fault.

Comment: +1 for "can occur way before the segmentation fault." The problem is probably not in the library (though sometimes it may be).

Comment: @ChrisLutz: but when the size is less than 500 bytes, it works with no problem.

Comment: @user537670 Can you upload demonstration files (JSON + simplified C code) to [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com) or so? Without code or input, we can just guess and give general hints.

Comment: @user537670 No offense, but that code is completely unrelated to the problem. Have a look at [sscce.org](http://sscce.org/) for how to generate a helpful example. Basically, answerers should be able to just type `gcc demo.c -o demo; ./demo demo.json` and end up with the same error that you get.

Comment: @user537670 - That sounds _exactly_ like a buffer overrun - when reading the file, presumably after the 500th byte you accidentally overwrite some important pointer housekeeping data, which later causes a crash.

Comment: @ChrisLutz: but the error says "json_object.c: No such file or  directory in json_object.c", so I am bit confused.

Comment: @user537670 As I wrote in the answer, that's just the line of code where your program tries to access a memory position that's not allocated. Check the allocation of `my->src`.

Comment: @phihag: my-> src is a character string of size 1024.

Answer (score 0):

Try using json_tokener_parse_verbose() instead of json_tokener_parse().

This worked for me insomuch as json_tokener_parse_verbose() returns a null pointer which is then picked up by is_error().